# check connection sharing network folder using username and password

Tags: vb.net, networking, networkcredentials

In my application check network folder connection using following code

```
Dim myIP As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(txtNetworkDrive.Text.Trim.Split("\", options:=StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0))
            Dim IPAddress As String = myIP.AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString


            Dim xStr As New System.Security.SecureString
            For Each c As Char In txtNetworkPassword.Text.Trim
                xStr.AppendChar(c)
            Next

            Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()

            psi.UserName = txtNetworkusername.text
            psi.Password = xStr
            psi.Domain = IPAddress 
            psi.FileName = txtNetworkDrive.Text
            psi.UseShellExecute = False
            Process.Start(psi)
```

The Input like

```
Network drive = "\\Sys4\shareddocs"

Network password= "sys4"
Network Username="user"
IPaddress="198.168.0.24"
```

But all time it show login failure bad username and password. what am doing wrong?
How get the solutions?

Comment: What does exactly mean `" in both network drive and password?

Comment: @varocarbas network drive is sharing drive / sharing folder. If you connect the sharing system in your system that time one dialog is show which is have user name and password. I mean that user name and password

Comment: It does not really matter where have you got this information from. What I think that might be relevant is the fact that some strings are preceded by special characters and some others are not. What seems to indicate that these strings include additional characters (or quotes within its value) which perhaps shouldn't be there (and which might be provoking the problem).

Comment: @varocarbas See my questions once again. i changed network drive an password

Comment: I have just highlighted something which might be provoking the problem. Your code seems fine to me (although cannot test it now on a shared network) and the error sounds descriptive (login information might be wrong). Sorry but cannot be of further help.